# Importing only part of a package to avoid circular import

Tags: python, import, package, circular-dependency

I've run into a circular import problem because I need to import only part of a package. When my program starts, I create a driver class which inherits from a class defined in a package, but another irrelevant part of that package imports the driver; I need to stop the irrelevant part of the package from running until it's needed later.

More info: I have a package of interfaces in my program. They're just parent objects with methods and attributes common to many objects in my program. They have no logical connection other than having similar purposes. They're in a package solely for my convenience; I don't want tons of .py files in the top level, and would rather sort them into subfolders.

The package looks like this:

`interfaces
__init__.py
destroyinterface.py
graphicsinterface.py`

And the __ init __.py looks like this:

`from destroyinterface import DestroyInterface
from graphicsinterface import GraphicsInterface`

I want to import DestroyInterface WITHOUT graphicsinterface.py being initialized. graphicsinterface.py imports the driver that's dependent on DestroyInterface, but I can't seem to access DestroyInterface to create the driver without graphicsinterface.py being initialized.

I don't want to remove the GraphicsInterface import from the __ init __.py because I don't want things to have to know it lives in a file called graphicsinterface.py when they import it. Including information about the structure of my packages to every single import both adds boilerplate and makes refactoring harder. I want the classes to be accessible for import directly from the interfaces module but their .py files only be initialized if I explicitly access them.

I don't want to use a lazy import of the driver in graphicsinterface.py either, both because it's messy (I only want the file being initialized when I actually need it) and because an import inside the time-sensitive methods of GraphicsInterface would slow them down.

Am I out of luck? Will I have to sort my files in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came across a hack to fix my problem. Figured I'd share it.

My __ init __.py now looks like this:

`class CrazyHack(object):
    @property
    def DestroyInterface(self):
        import crazyhackthing.destroyinterface
        return destroyinterface.DestroyInterface
    @property
    def GraphicInterface(self):
        import crazyhackthing.graphicinterface
        return graphicinterface.GraphicInterface
import sys
sys.modules["crazyhackthing"] = sys.modules["interfaces"]
sys.modules["interfaces"] = CrazyHack()`

This makes any import statements from this package refer to properties of the object defined there, and thus delay the initialization of files until explicit import. No idea if this works on python 3, and it's probably an awful idea in the first place, but it works for me. May God have mercy on my soul.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at two solutions within the graphics interface.  First, if only a couple of functions need the driver, import the driver in  those functions.  Doing an import of an already imported module is efficient, so it should be fine to import it in the driver.
Another approach is to do something like this in the graphics interface:

```
driver = None # filled in when driver is imported
```

Then elsewhere

```
import driver
import interfaces.graphics
interfaces.graphics.driver = driver
```